# How many blue marbles are in the jar?

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

On the table is are 10 jars, labeled with the number of assorted marbles contained within (say 1,000 and 1,000,000).

The goal is to estimate how many ***blue*** marbles are in each jar. Unfortunately the marbles are not evenly distributed and non-blue marbles may be clumped together (at an unpredictable rate).

You can pull as many samples of any size from the jar as you'd like (from any place in the jar). But each marble included in a sample costs $1 to check.

What are the most cost-effective strategies to estimate how many ***blue*** marbles are in each jar (say, `±20%` with `95%` probability)? Does the strategy differ based on the size of the jar?

For example, the first jar contains 1000 marbles, some of which are blue. I can pay $1000 to learn the exact amount of marbles.

**What is the best strategy to reach 95% confidence that my estimate would be within 20% of the actual?**

---

Example strategies for this first jar of 1k marbles:

- 50 Samples of 2 marbles (costs $100)
- 20 Samples of 10 marbles each (costs $200)
- 100 Samples of 5 marbles each (costs $500)

Comment: Please clarify if the margin of "error" allowed, $\pm 20\%$, is with 100$\%$ probability or is it possible to associate a probability with this error, say $95\%$ or other?

Comment: I see @bluemaster . Would it work to say "within 20% at least 95% of the time"?

Comment: I believe the easiest way to formulate the problem in such a way that you compute a confidence interval for the true value, at predefined probability, say 95$\%$,  fixing before hand the amplitude of the confidence interval. For example your estimation  would provide an answer such as between 105 and 115 blue marbles with probability 95$\%$, if the accepted amplitude is 10 marbles.

Comment: Sounds good @bluemaster . I edited the question based on your feedback. Is that better? In the meantime I'm playing around with confidence interval calculators to see where it takes me. So far I'm struggling to make the equation work. Can you put a little more detail into your example? Thanks for your help.